# R exporting text issue

Tags: r, utf-8

I have a problem that it might be a bit unique, but I think that if it is answered it could answer other questions about encoding too.

In order to expand my R skills I tried to write a function that I could manage the vcf file from android phones. Everything went ok, until I tried to upload the file in the phone. An error appeared that the first line starts with something else than a normal VCF version 3 file. But when I check the file on the PC it appears to be ok without these characters that my phone said. So, I asked about it and one person here said that it is the Byte Ordering Mark and I should use a HEX editor to see it. And it was there even it couldn't be seen in the TXT editor of windows and linux.

Thus, I tried to solve the problem by using fileEncoding arguments in R. the code that I use to write the file is:

```
write.table(cons2,file=paste(filename,".vcf",sep=""),row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=FALSE,fileEncoding="")
```

I put ASCII as argument, UTF-8 etc but no luck. ASCII seems to delete some of the characters, and UTF-8 makes these characters be visible in the text file.

I would appreciate if someone could provide a solution to this.

PS: I know that if I modify the file in a HEX editor it solves the problem, but I want the solution in the R coding.

Comment: So do you just want some R code that operates in hex? `as.hexmode` , `tools:showNonASCII` and so on?

Comment: I would appreciate if I could have a hint of how to save with the write.table() but without any reference (without the byte order mark) to the encoding in the exported text.